# How to test/debug cross-platforms desktop apps(Windows, MacOS) with limited resources

Tags: testing, deployment, electron, software-design, software-distribution

I am trying to build a desktop app.
I am thinking of using [electron](https://www.electronjs.org) on the recommendation of a web-developer friend of mine, 
but as I am the only sole developer, I don't have the means to test the software on different platforms(OS, hardware etc.).
So I am anticipating that this will cause a problem later, in the end, to test/debug software on different platforms and different OS.
I have ruled out web-apps because of some privacy concerns of the users for the remote data hosting.
Software is pretty lightweight and is almost equivalent to the image viewer apps with some slight modifications.
How to solve the problem of variations of different platforms?
Any literature suggestions pointing me in the general direction are also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it helps to think of Electron as two processes.

The `renderer` vs the `main` processes. Generally the renderer process which runs the HTML/CSS/JS is it's own isolated component, and you communicate to the `main` process using IPC.

So generally for the UI, you can use mostly any web based testing framework to test reliability. At [Amna](https://getamna.com), for example, we use [Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/) as our E2E testing platform. You an also use something like [QAWolf](https://www.qawolf.com/). Both should work with localhost. In general, most website testing tools should work fine, and consistently across platforms.

Where this gets tricky is when a UI functionality makes a call to the OS or the `main` process. For example, saving to the disk, or launching a program.

The general flow is this, and I've yet to find radically simpler options:

1. Set-Up a VM or buy a machine with the corresponding OS. I used Spot VMs in Azure for this.
2. Manually test the scenarios you care about in each VM before you ship

If you have a lot of cases that rely on the OS, then you should be able to further optimize this by using an automated test runner like [Spectron](https://www.electronjs.org/spectron).

From experience, what I've realized is that most of the iterations I do happen more on the UI than the underlying functions with the cross-platform capabilities. And if your code has good separation (e.g. `contextIsolation:true`, `nodeIntegration:false`), it should be pretty obvious when you need to do an entire "cross-platform" test vs just UI tests.

I'm not familiar with a lot of large-scale electron testing frameworks, I do know that [ToDesktop](https://www.todesktop.com/cli) handles package building and generating binaries to perform a smoke test and verify things open across different operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

The answer depends on *what* you are building, so it makes sense to figure out what you actually want to build. Some questions you might ask yourself:

- Do I need a database?
- Do I need authentication?
- Do I need portability?
- Do I need speed to market?
- Do I want to pick a language I'm familiar in?

These are all good questions and there are dozens more we all ask ourselves. However, back to your original question.

### Electron is a fine choice

Yes, there are [alternatives](https://github.com/sudhakar3697/electron-alternatives). But Electron is used for [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), [Facebook Messenger](https://www.messenger.com/desktop), [Microsoft Teams](https://products.office.com/en-US/microsoft-teams/group-chat-software) and [Figma](https://figma.com/). Choosing Electron means there are other developers making apps and there are proven apps in the market so you don't have to worry about a dead ecosystem.

Electron is easy to onboard if you know web technologies, think **js**, **html** and **css**. If you know these, you can transfer your web dev knowledge and make a cross-platform app. You don't have to worry about learning each OS since the UI is the webpage which will look mostly* the same between each OS. (*some very minor differences, but essentially the same).

### Cross-platform deployment is easy

There are [a few ways](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-distribution) of bringing your app to multiple platforms, *I* happen to be most familiar with [`electron-builder`](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder), but the other two solutions work as well.

### Many templates to start with

I am biased, since I'm the author of [`secure-electron-template`](https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-template) which is one of the [many templates](https://github.com/sindresorhus/awesome-electron#boilerplates) you can choose from when starting an app. However, I recently [reviewed all Electron templates](https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-template/wiki/State-of-Electron-frameworks-%5BMay-2021%5D) and found that only 4 do not have serious security vulnerabilities.

> The Electron framework frequently is updated, and over the course of the past few years there has been a shift in the way Electron apps are made. Some earlier frameworks didn't have good secure defaults which some of the older Electron templates inherited and thus, aren't as secure as new frameworks that follow [security guidelines](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security).

If you decide on Electron, give [my template](https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-template) a try. It's got a number of features I'm building out in order to help the community with features they might want (ie. internationalization (i18n), saving local data, custom context menus, page routing, e2e unit testing, and how one can use license key validation, to name a few things).

Comment: Thank for you this, Though you have answered it above but I am asking it again that there would not be many struggles I have to do develop the app for different Windows versions or mac os versions right?

Comment: @Beginner yes, it will be easier to make an app for different versions of Windows/ Mac OS/ Linux using Electron than if you went the traditional desktop app-development approach.